# Is it possible to assign default values to NAnt properties?

Tags: nant

I'd like to use the property value as a part of an argument passed to a certain EXE via `<exec/>` task. There's a condition which influences the property initialization, that is, if condition is true, it should contain value, otherwise be just empty (but still defined).

This is what I ended up so far:

```
<property name="prop1" value="" />
<property name="prop1" value="some-value-based-on-condition" if="condition-goes-here" />
```

And later on:

```
<exec program="my.exe">
  <arg value="C:\Root\Folder\${prop1}" />
  ...
</exec>
```

If the property is not set, I'd like to pass just `C:\Root\Folder\` as an argument value.

Initializing the property in this way seems too much for such a simple operation. Is there a way to do it simpler using what's in NAnt at the moment? I would imagine something like:

```
<property name="prop1" value="somevalue-based-on-condition" if="condition" default="" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example below should meet your needs. It will create a property named 'SolutionConfiguration' and assign it the value 'Release' if and only if the same parameter isn't already defined (ie. it was defined via the command line).

```
<property name="SolutionConfiguration" value="Release" unless="${property::exists('SolutionConfiguration')}" />
```

For your scenario, try

```
<property name="RootFolder" value="c:\Root\Folder" unless="${property::exists('RootFolder')}" />
<exec program="my.exe">
  <arg value="${RootFolder}\${prop1}" />
  ...
</exec>
```

Comment: Yes, this is close to what I need... anyway I think I should redesign my code to apply more with what NAnt offers... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `overwrite="False"`

```
<property name="RootFolder" value="c:\Root\Folder" overwrite="false" />
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer